# How to call a Method in a Cucumber - Step Definition

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I’m a newbie to Cucumber framework. I’m trying to call a Ruby method inside of a step definition. Here is how I define my method in lib/methods.rb

```
class Test_class

  def create_test_scenario()
   puts "here!!!"
  end

end
```

This is how I try to call the method inside of a step definition:

```
 And(/^I create scenarios$/) do
   Test_class.create_test_scenario
 end
```

I'm getting 'uninitialized constant Test_class (NameError)' when I run the test. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't instantiated the Test_class object.  For example:

```
class Test_class
  def create_test_scenario
    puts "here!!!"
  end
end

Test_class.new.create_test_scenario  # notice `new` method chained here
#=> here!!!
```

Errata:

Here's a link to [documentation](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/objinitialization.html) that explains the `initialize` method and how you can use it to set up object state on initialization.

For class (and module) names, the ruby convention is to use [`CamelCase`](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#camelcase-classes).  For example, `TestClass` instead of `Test_class`

Answer (score 0):

As orde has said, this is down to initialization. To help put the code into context, you would initialize the class object in your step definition as an instance variable (which starts with @). So it would look like this:

```
 And(/^I create scenarios$/) do
   @Test_class = Test_class.new
   @Test_class.create_test_scenario
 end
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks, Phonesis and orde. Phonesis, I initialize the class object in the step definition as you stated, but I'm still getting the same error: uninitialized constant Test_class (NameError). Any more suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You might need to set up an ENV.rb file which acts as a setup routine before the tests run. In that, you should include the class you need to initialize in a require statement. Something like this:                                       `$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../../features  /pages')`                                                                           
`require 'Test_class'`